# Searching results are always 0 (NSArray and NSPredicate)

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` which holds `Foo` objects defined like so:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject <NSCopying> {
    NSString *name;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

and the query:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", filterString];
//NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", filterString];
filteredArray = [[originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

and this is not working. I always get 0 results.

So, my question is:

Should I always use `NSPredicate` for searching only `NSDictionary` objects with a certain key or can I use it for searching any object as long as there is a property/method that matches the query (in this case: name)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct.  I tried it:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
@implementation Foo

@synthesize name;

@end

NSMutableArray * a = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    Foo * f = [[Foo alloc] init];
    [f setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    [a addObject:f];
    [f release];
}

NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", @"1"];
NSArray * filtered = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
NSLog(@"%@", [filtered valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Logs:

```
2010-10-29 10:51:22.103 EmptyFoundation[49934:a0f] (
    1,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19
)
```

Which leads me to ask:  Is your `originalArray` empty?

Comment: thanks, indeed it seems correct, I realized that my error was somewhere else. ;(